# Passing Self-Refreshing Changing Variable

Tags: javascript, variables, geolocation

I'm making a web application that lets people, with an invitation, track other people. I'm using javascript geolocation. I need a variable that passes to another page, but also needs to be refreshed every five seconds or so. All this is done only when the person who is being tracked is on the first page. A database accessed with ajax and the variable changing every five seconds seems like overkill.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try localStorage
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

That will store data into the browser, but associated with that particular URL.  So the page can always access it.

If that doesn't fit the bill, look into sessionStorage or indexedDB.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

Comment: So localStorage is accessible by other browsers?

Comment: No. localStorage is not accessible by other browsers.  If you need it across browsers, then you need remote storage.  
If you don't have control over a remote server, then kinvey.com (google) or parse.com (facebook) might be of use. They are like instant backends. There are other providers as well. They are simple remote key/value stores with authorization.